# PROC FREQ - How to find out the dataset name

Tags: sas

I have a program where few datasets are created dynamically through a macro. Datasets are also named dynamically.

For example:
STAT_FILE_1,
STAT_FILE_2

Sometimes my macro may create two datasets,
STAT_FILE_1,
STAT_FILE_2

and sometimes, three
STAT_FILE_1,
STAT_FILE_2,
STAT_FILE_3

and the number may vary depending on the source data.

I am using PROC FREQ to have a summary data for the last/recent dataset.

Hence I am using the below code

```
PROC FREQ;
tables YEAR;
run;
```

I am getting the result, however i am not able to find out the dataset name used. Can some please help me in finding the dataset name which is used in PROC FREQ.

Comment: This will show you the last table created:%put &syslast;

Comment: Hi Stig, Thank you so much for your input! This is what i expected to give in my result.

Comment: @StigEide Can you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show you the last table created:

```
%put &syslast;
```

Comment: As a side-note &SYSNOBS will give you the number of rows from the last dataset that was opened. Just as &SQLOBS give you the number of rows from the last SQL. There is an undocumented automatic macrovariable called SQLXOBS that seems to be the number of rows from the last SQL passthrough.